# How to parse GeoJSON in TypeScript with the geojson module and the @types/geojson type?

Tags: typescript, types, leaflet, gis, geojson

My TypeScript application is reporting that property `parse` does not exist on `./path/to/node_modules/@types/geojson/index`. Which is true when inspecting the interfaces for the [geojson type definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/geojson?activeTab=code).

The `geojson` module does however offer a [parse](https://github.com/caseycesari/GeoJSON.js/blob/727037c732cef7f2c123a340dfdc2ff9f5de9294/geojson.js#L38) method.

**How can I access the `parse` method?**

I tried removing the `@types/geojson` module which seems to make the method accessible. However, despite having removed the type definition the same exception is thrown *or*, in another scenario I've not been able to replicate, VS Code throws an error that a type definition is recommended and won't compile without it.

I added the `// @ts-ignore` decorator to disable the error but I'd prefer a cleaner fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you bumped on a rare case where a DefinitelyTyped `@types/xxx` package does NOT describe the same named `xxx` package on npm...

- [`@types/geojson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/geojson?activeTab=readme) definition describes the GeoJSON standard

> This package contains type definitions for geojson (https://geojson.org/).

```json
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/geojson/package.json#L5
{
    "name": "@types/geojson",
    "nonNpm": true,
    "nonNpmDescription": "geojson"
}
```

- [`geojson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson) on npm is actually a library to *parse* such GeoJSON objects...

As [mentioned in the README](https://github.com/caseycesari/GeoJSON.js/tree/727037c732cef7f2c123a340dfdc2ff9f5de9294?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) of that library:

> For Typescript environments, you can use GeoJSON.ts, a Typescript-native library.
> [@EugeneYWang/GeoJSON.ts](https://github.com/eugeneYWang/GeoJSON.ts)

...and [the full explanation](https://github.com/eugeneYWang/GeoJSON.ts?tab=readme-ov-file#the-reason-to-create-this-repo) on the latter:

> **The reason to create this repo**
>
> Usually, an existed NPM package can just be used in TypeScript if a type definition file with the same name of that package is also installed. So why should I refactor that library into this typescript one? The reason is that the type definition named as GeoJSON has been occupied as the type definition of GeoJSON standard specification. Therefore, no one could contribute a type definition in TypeDefinition for @caseycesari/GeoJSON.js.